# Two semi stable limit cycles with disjoint interior

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, flows, limit-cycles

What is  a  precise example of  a  quadratic  vector  field on the plane  with at least one semi stable limit cycles?

Furthermore, is there a quadratic polynomial vector field on the plane with two semi stable limit cycles with disjoint interiors?