# Homothety vector fields generating a foliation of $S^3$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

Inspired by [this question on homothety vector fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153581/does-for-every-vector-field-there-always-exist-a-volume-form-for-which-the-vecto) we realize that non homotheticity is some how an intrinsic property of the foliation associated to the vector field. See the comment by Prof. Bryant $x^2\partial_x+xy\partial_y$. However it is a singular foliation but the dynamical feature is an obstruction for homothecity since the origin attracts the left part $x<0$ and it repels the right part $x>0$. The non singular case is mentioned   in [my answer to that question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/437459/36688) indicating to semi stable limit cycle, very simillar concept to the interesting situation in the comment of Prof. Bryant.

So the dynamical obstruction mentioned above is a motivation to ask the following generalized question:

> Assume that we have a 2 dimensional foliation of $S^3$. Are there two independent homothety vector fields tangent to the foliation(Homothety with respect to some volume form)? A weaker version: Is there a homothety vector field (wrt some volum form) tangent to the foliation?