# Volume-preserving projective transformations are isometries

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

What is a simple, elementary proof of the following result?

*A continuously differentiable map from the unit sphere $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ $(n > 1)$ to itself that preserves volumes and sends great circles to great circles is an isometry.*

I have a simple, but non-elementary proof of a more general result:

*A continuously differentiable map from a Zoll Riemannian or reversible Finsler manifold to itself that preserves volumes and sends  geodesics  to geodesics is an isometry.*

I don't think the generality makes the result more interesting (non-isometries sending geodesics to geodesics are not very many except in the case of real projective spaces and spheres) and I wonder if there is some easy, quick argument that takes care of the case of spheres with their canonical metrics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you must now given your title, there is a first classical argument that shows that (except for $n=1$, a case taking care of itself) if your map sends great circle to great circles, it must be projective, i.e. come from a linear map i.e. be a composition of a linear map with central projection to the sphere.

In particular, it also sends totally geodesic subspheres of every dimension to totally geodesic subspheres of the same dimension. Now, the volume assumption implies that it must preserve the angles between any two equators (since it preserves the volumes of the pieces cut out by these two equators). This shows that the map is conformal, and since it preserves the volume it must be an isometry.

Comment: Oh, by the way: you do not need as much regularity as you assumed.

Comment: ... in particular, being a bijection is enough for the map to belong to $PGL(n+1,R)$ (for $n\ge 2$).

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: bien vu! Exactly the sort of elementary argument I was looking for.

Comment: @Misha and Benoit: the title was for "connoisseurs", the statement of the result was to make it independent of previous acquaintance with projective geometry. Besides, in the general case I do need $C^1$.

Answer (score 4):

A pair (projective structure, volume form) allows one  to canonically 
 construct a torsion-free   affine connection.  This affine connection  belongs to the projective structure and has the property that the volume form is parallel. It is an easy exercise to show its (local) existence; this  affine structure is  unique modulo multiplication by a constant. Thus, your map is affine for this affine connection (which is the Levi-Civita connection of the standard metric on the sphere by your assumptions) and since the metric of the sphere is  irreducible you map must  preserve the metric.

As you see the proof works for any Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian metric and give also half of the answer on you second question. Moreover, it is a local  proof and you do not need that the geodesics are closed.   I did not think about the finslerian analog of this statement but would not be suprised if a similar statement holds in the finslerian case.

A related question is [Projectively equivalent connections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122311/projectively-equivalent-connections/122334#122334)

Comment: The "second question" was not a question, but the statement of a result. I like your local argument made global by the irreducibility of the metric. I guess that what you say about projective structures and volume forms can be found in the works of Veblen and Young, right? Not the projective geometry books, but their papers on projective connections. Is there a more modern reference?

Comment: Unfortunately as a rule I do not know references for results that can be proven on one line. May be result stays in Eastwood's ``notes on projective geometry'' and if one wants  one can explain this result with the help of deep mathematics but as  I said it is easy to prove than to look for references

Comment: We all have to cite results we can prove ourselves. The reference is not so much to the result as to the construction. Is it yours?

Comment: That a nonvanishing density of nontrivial weight is preserved by a unique torsion-free connection representing a given projective structure has been used since the 1920s. Probably if you look in H. Weyl's 1921 paper in which projective equivalence was introduced, it can be found there, at least implicitly. Certainly Veblen, Young, Thomas, etc. knew this fact explicitly. The general fact is that for a parabolic geometry modeled on $G/P$ with $G$ semisimple and $P$ parabolic there is a notion of Weyl structures parameterized by sections of a certain line bundle. See the book of Cap and Slovak.

Comment: To Alvarez and @Dan Fox:  the construction is  definitly not mine, I have understood it speaking with people from parabolic geometry and these people indeed read Thomas very carefully. Contrary to what Dan is saying, I do not think that Weyl 1921 is a good reference since the construction is not there and which is not the first place  projective equivalence was introduced (I suggest Beltrami 1864 or  Levi-Civita 1896).  And citing the wonderful book of Cap and Slovak in this context can be very misleading for a reader of your paper. Sorry for no help but may be Dan can give a precise referens

Comment: @Matveev: It is hard to write precisely in these small comment boxes. My use of the word "first" was unfortunate and wrong; certainly you are right that the notion of projective equivalence is much older than Weyl. What maybe is not so much older is the explicit notion of projective equivalence of affine connections as such (maybe due to Weyl?). The paper of Weyl is one of the older ones where one finds the projective Weyl and Schouten tensors. Anyone writing these things down has to implicitly understand that a choice of volume fixes an affine connection representing the projective structure.

Comment: @Matveev: to continue my comment, an explicit reference where this fact is stated explicitly is the italicized lemma on p. 104 of Eisenhart's 1927 book Non-Riemannian Geometry. Actually Eisenhart speaks only of normalizing the trace of the Christoffel symbols by an appropriate choice of coordinates and not explicitly of volume forms, but this is equivalent, and the uniqueness is explicit. In a footnote Eisenhart references a 1926 paper of JM Thomas (TAMS v.28 n.4) where the same result is stated as Theorem 1.

Comment: To complete the comment: in these old references there is not usually explicit mention of volume forms (except in Weyl), rather they speak of choosing coordinate systems, and relate the trace of the Christoffel symbols to the Jacobian of the coordinate transformations. To me this seems a matter of language - at the time they mostly worked locally, and the language of tensors/forms/densities was not used in the modern way.

Comment: A modern reference where the fact is stated explicitly (in terms of volume forms) is Proposition 4 of Nomizu and Pinkall's paper in Tohoku 39 (1987). Finally, my mention of Cap and Slovak was meant only to give a refence for Matveev's "help of deep mathematics". If one works out explicitly what are "Weyl structures" and "bundles of scales" for the parabolic geometries corresponding to projective structures one gets back to the statement that there is a unique torsion free representative of a projective class of connections inducing a given principal connection on the bundle of volume densities

Comment: To finish: I agree with what I think Matveev is saying - that from a modern perspective this is an immediate one-line proof fact that requires no citation. It's much much simpler than many other things (e.g. uniformization) that we all use without citation.